# Use one web.configu transform from multiple publish profiles

Tags: asp.net, web-config, publishing, web.config-transform

Is there a way to use one `web.config` transform (say `web.test.config`) with multiple Publish Profiles? (i.e. '**Publish - test - server 1**' and '**Publish - test - server 2**').

As I understand the name of the profile must match the name of the config transform; is there a way to override it?